# Spring bean constructor-arg with generic

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, autowired

I'll let my code talk for me, first, here's my root-context.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="it.trew.prove" />

<bean id="usersDao" class="it.trew.prove.model.dao.UsersDao" />

<bean id="usersService" class="it.trew.prove.server.services.UsersServiceImpl" />
```

Some of my users dao:

```
public class UsersDao extends ObjectifyDao<User> {

    protected UsersDao(Class<User> clazz) {
        super(User.class);
    }

    static {
        ObjectifyService.register(User.class);
    }       
}
```

And my users service (implementation):

```
public class UsersServiceImpl implements UsersService {

    private final UsersDao usersDao;

    @Autowired
    public UsersServiceImpl(UsersDao usersDao) {
        this.usersDao = usersDao;
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> listUsers() {
        return usersDao.list();
    }

    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        usersDao.add(user);
    }
}
```

Now my log is:

> AVVERTENZA: Nested in
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'usersController' defined in file
>   [/home/fabio/stsworkspace/TestGAE/target/TestGAE-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/it/trew/prove/web/UsersController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [it.trew.prove.server.services.UsersService]: : Error
>   creating bean with name 'usersService' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type
>   [it.trew.prove.model.dao.UsersDao]: : Error creating bean with name
>   'usersDao' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class [it.trew.prove.model.dao.UsersDao]: No default
>   constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   it.trew.prove.model.dao.UsersDao.(); nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'usersDao' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class [it.trew.prove.model.dao.UsersDao]: No default
>   constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   it.trew.prove.model.dao.UsersDao.(); nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'usersService' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type
>   [it.trew.prove.model.dao.UsersDao]: : Error creating bean with name
>   'usersDao' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class [it.trew.prove.model.dao.UsersDao]: No default
>   constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   it.trew.prove.model.dao.UsersDao.(); nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'usersDao' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class [it.trew.prove.model.dao.UsersDao]: No default
>   constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   it.trew.prove.model.dao.UsersDao.():
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   it.trew.prove.model.dao.UsersDao.()

So... in your honest opinion, **how can I change my code to make it work correctly?**

- Sorry for being so verbose :) -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the constructor argument to the configuration file

```
<bean id="usersDao" class="it.trew.prove.model.dao.UsersDao">
  <constructor value="it.trew.prove.model.dao.User" />
</bean>
```

or much better, **remove the useless paramter from the UserDao constructor**!

and add `autowire="constructor"` for the user service bean declaration.
`<bean id="usersService" class="it.trew.prove.server.services.UsersServiceImpl" autowire="constructor"/>`

Answer (score 1):

> No default constructor found; nested exception is java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:

Just add default constructor

Answer (score 0):

To get your `@Autowire` annotation to work you must add [`<context:annotation-config />`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config) .E.g.,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```

Comment: from the doc:Element : component-scan
Scans the classpath for annotated components that 
 will be auto-registered as Spring beans. ...
 detected. Note: This tag implies the effects of the 
 'annotation-config' tag, activating \@Required, 
\@Autowired...